# Why is my table cutting off text upon attempted resizing? Also why is the table not located even at the top with my name?

Tags: html, css

------HTML CODE------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>********* ******** | Jr Developer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/portfolioStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body >
        <header id="nameAndContact">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>********* ********</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <td>Contact Information</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Email:</th>
                        <td>mac************@*****.com</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Phone:</th>
                        <td>***-***-****</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="selfTitleAndDesc">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Full Stack Developer and Designer</h1>
                <h2>I write functional and simple to understand code with a strong working knowledge of front and back-end services</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

--------END HTML CODE--------

--------CSS CODE-------------

```
.container{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#nameAndContact h1{
    float:auto;
    width:70%;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nameAndContact table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    padding:0 30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

@media(max-width:700px){
    #nameAndContact h1{
        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }
    #nameAndContact table{
        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

--------END CSS CODE---------

The issue I'm having is that when i resize the window in my browser, the email and the words 'Contact Information' start to get cut off on the right side of the screen. Do i need to wrap the text within the table in some way? Is there an issue with the percentages I am using for both my h1 and my table? Also not certain as to the reason my table is not being displayed in line with my h1. Any help is greatly appreciated i'm fairly new to web coding, thank you all :).

Comment: And before anyone says it I realize it's ironic that my portfolio says that i write 'functional and simple to understand code' hahaha, the goal is that I am able to do that by the time I am sending this portfolio to employers :P.

Comment: seems ok in codepen https://codepen.io/mdnelles/pen/rNVRJop - what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the stuff i commented out:

- inline doesnt work with float
- width 30% is not stable, i would recommend using pixels and changing them in `@media`
- padding was just taking unnecessary space

```
#nameAndContact table {
   table-layout: fixed;
   /*display: inline;*/
   float: right;
   /*width: 30%;*/
   /*padding: 0 30px;*/
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

then add this to your css:

- shorten the first column because it doesnt need to be that big, so i give it a fixed size

```
#nameAndContact table th:first-of-type {
   width: 90px;
}
```

I would also recommend checking out table structure (where is td where th etc.) https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

For media queries to work correctly, you need this in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Or some variant of that.
The link below provides more in-depth information regarding the use of the Responsive Meta Tag.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/